# Otimizar busca Ajax que apresenta lentidão

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou com problema de lentidão nessa pesquisa em ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nome').keyup(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        $.post('../Ajax/busca_nome', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
            $('#resultado').html(busca);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ela busca no banco de dados a cada caractere digitado, desde o 1º.

Gostaria que ela começasse a pesquisar depois do 4º caractere digitado. Como posso alterar meu código para isso acontecer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode verificar através de `string.length`.

A função ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nome').keyup(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        if(chars.length > 4){
          $.post('../Ajax/busca_nome', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
             $('#resultado').html(busca);
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gquwvffk/

Comment: Exatamente isso amigo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu pensaria em fazer um if antes de realizar a chamada ajax. Só chamando se o valor do campo fosse maior ou igual a 4. Segue o código abaixo:

```
    if( this.val().length >= 4 ){
       $.post('../Ajax/busca_nome', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
           $('#resultado').html(busca);
       });

    }
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.

Comment: Funcionou também. Obrigado amigo. Ajudou muito, abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que há mais melhorias que deves fazer para além daquelas sugeridas nas outras repostas.

- usa uma [função debounce](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54052/129) ou throttle
- coloca em cache elementos que precisas de usar muitas vezes.

Se usares uma função debounce o ajax espera alguns milisegundos mais antes de fazer cada pedido ajax. Em vez de fazer um pedido por tecla premida, ele espera pela ultima tecla e depois faz o pedido. Como estamos a fazar de intervalos de tempo muito pequenos o utilizador não é afetado.

Colocando em cache por exemplo `$('#resultado')` faz com que não precises de ir ao DOM vezes demais para saber qual é esse elemento.

O teu código poderia então ficar assim:

```
(function() { // para não exportar variáveis para o escopo global
    function debounce(fn, delay) { // defenição da função debounce
        var timer = null;
        return function() {
            var context = this,
                args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, delay);
        };
    }

    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado'); // colocar o elemento em cache
    var handler = debounce(function() { // criar uma função com debounce
        var chars = this.value;
        if (chars.length < 4) return; // parar aqui se o texto fôr muito curto
        $.post('../Ajax/busca_nome', {
            val: chars
        }, function(busca) {
            resultado.innerHTML = busca;
        });
    }, 400); // 400 ms de espera depois da ultima tecla
    $('#nome').keyup(handler); // passar a super função ao jQuery
})();
```

Comment: Muito bom cara. Valeu mesmo. Abraço.